# Symfony Twig, undefined index for persistent collection

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
{{ dump(memory.memoryImages) }}
```

gives me:
[image]

But

```
{{ dump(memory.memoryImages.getValues) }}
```

or

```
{{ dump(memory.memoryImages.first) }}
```

or

```
{% for memoryImage in memory.memoryImages %}
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

all give me:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: Memory").

How can I get the `memoryImage` from `memoryImages`? Did I might got wrongly configured doctrine mappings?

Entity Memory has a oneToMany relation:

```
oneToMany:
    memoryImages:
        targetEntity: MemoryImage
        mappedBy: Memory
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

and MemoryImages Entity has a ManyToOne relation:

```
manyToOne:
    memory:
        targetEntity: Memory
        inversedBy: memorieImages
        joinColumn:
            name: memory_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: Check your Mapping files. memory instead of Memory? Regards

Comment: @Albeis updated question with the relevant mapping part...

Comment: Try mappedBy: memory

Comment: @Albeis thank you, now it works!

Comment: I have to add that any problem with configuration of mapping can lead to this error. So to avoid it the general solution is to run command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` and you will find the answer why you have such problem.
Hope this help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are not calling `Memory` instead of your `memory` (maybe even somewhere higher up) cause the error message should reflect that with its proper case (note the capital letter).

As for accessing values a loop etc like you are showing should just be fine so another reason why I doubt its these little things, but in fact the most tiniest of things.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I've updated the question with the relation between Memory and MemoryImages ... those tiny things make my life hard sometimes :)

Comment: The mapped by should be lower case no? its not the entity name for 'Memory' but the field name in MemoryImage?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple different typos:

```
oneToMany:
    memoryImages:
        targetEntity: MemoryImage
        mappedBy: Memory             => mappedBy: memory // Use field name not field type
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]

manyToOne:
    memory:
        targetEntity: Memory
        inversedBy: memorieImages    => inversedBy: memoryImages // Field name doesn't match
        joinColumn:
             name: memory_id
             referencedColumnName: id
```